# How can I define a default value in a tabulator js column editor

Tags: tabulator

I'm using the property `{editor: "input"}`. How can I set a default value in the input field, when I add a new row programmatically .

```
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name", sorter:"string", width:200, editor:true},
    {title:"Age", field:"age", sorter:"number", align:"right", formatter:"progress"},
    {title:"Gender", field:"gender", sorter:"string", cellClick:function(e, cell){console.log("cell click")},},
    {title:"Height", field:"height", formatter:"star", align:"center", width:100},
    {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col", sorter:"string"},
    {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob", sorter:"date", align:"center"},
    {title:"Cheese Preference", field:"cheese", sorter:"boolean", align:"center", formatter:"tickCross"},
],
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ***input*** editor will have the value of the cell by default.

If you want to add a new row with a value already set in the ***name*** column for example you would pass it into the object on the ***addRow*** function:

```
table.addRow({name:"steve"});
```

If you want to present the user with a list of available options then i would suggest using the ***selecct*** or ***autocomplete*** editors instead.

Full details on the available built in editors can be found in the [Editing Data Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit)

If you want a specific behaviour outside of the standard input element, you can always implement your own custom editor. Have a look at the [Custom Editor Example](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit#edit-custom) for more information on how to do this